# How to start one of several installed Python 2 versions?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

Given several installed versions of Python 2 on OS X (e.g. 2.7.5, 2.7.11), how to explicitly start one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find where the python binary you want is located and run it. At the command line:

```
/path/to/python-275
```

Comment: Finding the path is the problem. If I do `whereis python275` or `which 275`, I get nothing back. Same goes for `python2.7.5`.